# Why can't I get on Clash of Clans?

Tags: technical-issues, clash-of-clans

Device Information: iPhone 4S, running iOS 9.1.
Clash of Clans Information: **Version**: latest, **Username**: ProsecutorPayne, **TH**: 6, **Clan**: awesome clan

I cannot get on Clash of Clans. What's happening is that the Supercell logo comes up with its little jingle, and then everything freezes, like so:
                                           [image: Frozen Supercell Logo]

Is it possible to get past this point? This has been happening only for the past few days, so I don't know what's wrong. May I please have help?

Comment: I'm not sure if we can help you fix this. I recommend contacting supercell directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen the game fail to come up like this from time to time. Sometimes it also fails when "Loading" from the first screen.

Here are the steps I recommend trying (in order)

1. Force Quit the app (*double press the home key, fling the app up or down to close it). Then restart.
2. Verify/update to the latest version of the game using the App Store.
3. Double check your WiFi strength (and/or data connection).  A weak signal may prevent start up... if so, see the next step.  If you try to run the app using free WiFi - like at Starbucks - you may need to complete some agreement step in a browser first before wifi is really active.
4. If you have a data plan, try turning OFF WiFi.
5. Power off the device, then back on.  Start again with step 3.
6. Delete and reload the game.

Comment: I tried all of those except 5, and only 4 worked as a tempfix (after one or two loads it would glitch again) but it was later fixed in an update. Thanks!

Comment: Good point. I've added "update to the lastest version of the game" to the list of things to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well in my opinion the fault lies with your device, do this:
 1. Unistall the game 
 2. Log Out from Game Center
 3. Download offline package(installer) of COC's latest version
 4. Log onto GameCenter and finally install the game
 5. Hope this helps rectify the issue